# Creating a noSql database, what is the best source code to look at?

Tags: java, rest, nosql, comments, sharding

I have always wanted a nosql database that was purpose built for storing large volumes of nested/threaded comments. Implementation would probably be done in java because that is what I am best at.  I really like how ElasticSearch is dead simple to set up a cluster and throw data into it, I want my product to share those same qualities.  Here are the features I have in mind:

1) auto/manual sharding across clusters
2) auto/manual indexing across clusters
3) full text search (probably via lucene or elasticSearch)
4) REST/JSON API
5) retrieve any comment by ID
6) comments can be retrieved with or without child nodes
7) comment trees can be retrieved with a specified depth
8) comment tree can be retrieved can be filtered by time or rank
9) entire comment trees can be re-parented.

What I'm looking for are exceptional pieces of code or specific algorithms that I can study before digging into this project.  Can anyone suggest a few places to get started?

Comment: Much of this will be a feature of the app you build rather than the database you use.  The rest (possibly excluding full-text search), any existing NoSQL database should be able to handle.  Why exactly can't you use an already existing DB?

Comment: Do you want to write your own, or do you want to use one that you like and that is written in Java?

Comment: About 80% of the reason for wanting to write my own is for fun, the other 20% is because I have never really been fully satisfied with the traditional solutions for storing nested comments.  I think it would be cool to be able to fire up a cluster to store/search reddit scale volumes of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since your tag in a question indicates Java, I
 suggest looking into OrientDB.

Here is a source code:

http://code.google.com/p/orient/source/browse/

and the architecture:

http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Presentations

for the big boy stuff (clustering, hyper scaling take a look at HBase and Accumulo):

http://hbase.apache.org/source-repository.html

http://accumulo.apache.org/source.html

Hope this helps.
Edmon